# How to combine Processing with Sublime Text 2

Tags: windows, text, functional-programming, processing

[Windows 7, X64]

Hello.
I'd like to combine Processing with Sublime Text 2, but i can't do that.

**WHAT I DID:**

1. Installed Processing and Sublime Text 2.
2. Installed Package Control in Sublime Text 2 using the code from [packagecontrol.io](https://packagecontrol.io/installation).
3. Installed Processing in Sublime Text 2 using Package Control.
4. After that I followed the instruction from https://github.com/b-g/processing-sublime to install processing-java:

> 1. Open the "Advanced System Settings" by running sysdm.cpl
> 2. In the "System Properties" window, click on the Advanced tab.
> 3. In the "Advanced" section, click the Environment Variables button.
> 4. Edit the "Path" variable.
> 5. Append the processing path (e.g. ;C:\Program\Files\Processing-2.0b6) to the variable value. Each entry is separated with a semicolon.

**SO, RIGHT NOW I HAVE:**

PATH: C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Program Files (x86)\Processing-2.2.1

Path: C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;Z:\usr\local\php5;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Autodesk Shared\;Z:\home\yii\framework\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Skype\Phone\;C:\Program Files (x86)\QuickTime\QTSystem\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Processing-2.2.1

**BUT:**

When I click "Build" in Sublime Text 2, i have this in the console:

> Running processing-java --sketch=C:\Arthur\Generative Art\test 1\build --output=C:\Артур\Generative Art\test 1\build/build-tmp --run --force
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File ".\sublime_plugin.py", line 337, in run_
>
> File ".\exec.py", line 154, in run
>
> File ".\exec.py", line 45, in **init**
>
> UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xca in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)

And Processing doesn't show the result of the code.

**HOW** can I fix that? Please, help me!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in the processing file path ("C:\Артур\Generative Art\test 1\build/build-tmp --run --force"), it contains cyrillic symbols. Just try to rename folder "Артур". Удачи)